# how to install Moodle with Postgre

Tags: php, moodle

i am installing Moodle 2.1 with postgre database. the problem i am facing is that it gives me error

> PHP has not been properly configured with the PGSQL extension so that
>   it can communicate with PostgreSQL. Please check your php.ini file or
>   recompile PHP.

i have adjusted all the required extension for pgsql. but still i get the same error. i have even created a database in postgre (an empty database) but still i didnt work.

please help me

thanks

Comment: I've created a proposal for a Stack Exchange website for Moodle users and developers. This question would be a perfect fit for it, rather than for Stack Overflow. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33861/virtual-learning-environments

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried (command line):

```
apt-get install php5-pgsql
apache2ctl restart
```

Or:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Comment: I have that package, and also have the same problem. Are there any other files that could be checked? I can't find in the moodle installation the php.ini file also.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it was not installed, and installing fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of trouble, because the version of Moodle I have (3.3) wants a newer version of php than I have on my Ubuntu 14.04.  I had 5.5.9 and Moodle insisted on 5.6.  So I upgraded php5 to php5.6 with a special ppa.  But what happened was it put the new php5.6 next to the old one.  So I kept having trouble with Apache, until I set soft links to libphp5.so from my new libphp5.6.so, and set the conf and load files in mods-available to the new php5.6 versions.

Then I had a problem with the postgresql php driver.  I tried installing php5-pgsql and it was always linking back to the old php 5.5.9 on Ubuntu!  This did not make moodle happy.  Then I discovered that there is a php5.6-pgsql.  I uninstalled my php5-pgsql and installed php5.6-pgsql.  Uff.  And added these two lines to php.ini (inside the /etc/php5/apache2 directory):

extension=/usr/lib/php/20131226/pdo_pgsql.so
extension=/usr/lib/php/20131226/pgsql.so

Now moodle can move on to the next error (the php xml extension)!

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install php5-pgsql fixed it for me despite the fact that my vhost on Plesk runs PHP7.0. Now I can use the CLI in Moodle with PostgreSQL.